# PHP - IF statement best scenario

Tags: php, performance

Tried to find a similar question but nothing came up. If you find any related please tell me and I'll close this one.
Ok so I have the next code snippet:

```
$fruits = ['Banana', 'Kiwi', 'Apple'];
$fruits_no = count($fruits);
```

Now lets say that we need to check if any values are stored within the Array or is NULL/Empty before I'm doing any further statements. For this I have two possible IF:

```
if ($fruits_no > 0) { }
```

or

```
if ($fruits) { } // Evaluates to TRUE since any positive Integer is TRUE
```

My question is which of these two are better from performance view?

Comment: There is no appreciable performance issue in such a simple statement, go for the most readable choice for you.

Comment: Performance-wise you'll need hundreds of thousands of iterations, which result in premature optimization.

Comment: @Eugen Zaharia: Any positive and NEGATIVE integer evaluvates to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't clear enough, but I'll leave multiple options.

First, if you want to check if array is(not) empty, then there's [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) in PHP for that. Note, that before PHP 5.5 this can not be used with expressions - thus, if your data is a result of some expression, that will be error in prior PHP versions.

Second, empty array isn't same as array with empty values. For example,

```
$a = [];
$b = [''];

var_dump(empty($a), empty($b));//true, false
```

-so you should decide what to do. Fortunately, there's an easy way to transform array and get rid of empty values. That's [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
$fruits = ['', 0];
var_dump(array_filter($fruits));//array(0) { }
```

Therefore, you can use it and combine with `empty()` check. And this is why I've mentioned version-dependent behavior of `empty()` - in PHP 5.5 such check can be done as:

```
if(!empty(array_filter($fruits)))
{
}
```

-but not in PHP<=5.4. In those versions, you'll have to store result of `array_filter()` in separate variable before applying `empty()`

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the best way to check if an array is empty is using [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/empty). For example:

```
if(!empty($fruits))
{
    // $fruits is not empty.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this possible conditions for your example.

```
<?php 
$fruits = ['Banana', 'Kiwi', 'Apple'];

if($fruits["0"])
{
    /* Present */ 
}
if($fruits["0"] !="")
{
    /* Present */ 
}

if(isset($fruits["0"]))
{
    /* Present */ 
}

if($fruits["0"] == NULL)
{
    /* Not Present */ 
}

if($fruits["0"] == "")
{
    /* Not Present */ 
}
?>
```